# Runtime error in C++ with eigen library, any suggestions?

Tags: c++, eigen

I am new to C++ and eigen library. I am trying to code some simple stuff, but do not know where I am going wrong. Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Eigen\Dense>
#include<cmath>
#include<fstream>

  using namespace std;
  using namespace Eigen;

  int main (int argc, char* argv[])
  {
      int n = 200;

      Matrix<double, Dynamic,1> u_n;
      u_n.setZero(n,1);

      Matrix<double, Dynamic,1> u_n_minus_one;
      u_n_minus_one.setZero(n,1);

      Matrix<double, Dynamic,1> u_n_plus_one;
      u_n_plus_one.setZero(n,1);

      std::ofstream fileWriter ("Values.txt");
      assert(fileWriter.is_open());

      float r=2;
      float F=100;

      for (int t=0;t<=5;t=t+1)
      {


                u_n_plus_one (0,0) =0;
//source of error
                u_n_plus_one.block(1,0,n-1,0) = pow(r,2)*( u_n.block(1,0,n-2,0)+ u_n.block(3,0,n,0)) + 2*(1-pow(r,2))*u_n.block(1,0,n-1,0)-u_n_minus_one.block(1,0,n-1,0);
//source of error
                u_n_plus_one (floor(n/2),0)=F;
                u_n_plus_one (n-1,0) =0 ;    //corrected from (n,0) to (n-1,0)


    u_n_minus_one = u_n ;
    u_n = u_n_plus_one ;

    //writing values to file
    if (remainder(t, 10) == 0)
    {
        fileWriter<<u_n.transpose()<<std::endl;
    }

   }

      fileWriter.close();
  }
```

I am trying to declare a few matrices (though they are vectors). Then I am doing operations on blocks of matrices, and finally writing the results to the file. I did not get any compile time error, but program crashes during run.

I tried debugging the code and  the error seem to lie within *//source of error* statements. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Does it say what kind of runtime error it is?

Comment: I got this runtime error: I think it has to do something with matrix indexing.
`Assertion failed: a_startRow >= 0 && blockRows >= 0 && a_startRow <= xpr.rows()
- blockRows && a_startCol >= 0 && blockCols >= 0 && a_startCol <= xpr.cols() - b
lockCols, file C:\MinGW\Eigen3.2.1/Eigen\src/Core/Block.h, line 141

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
`

Comment: That is a long, complicated line. You might want to consider breaking up that computation with intermediate variables, at least while debugging. That will help you narrow it down.

Comment: You have a cycle on t, but you don't seem to use t anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

As the page on [Block operations](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialBlockOperations.html) says, `matrix.block(i,j,p,q)` denotes the block with `p` rows and `q` columns starting at the `(i,j)` entry. I think that `u_n.block(3,0,n,0)` in the program is supposed to refer to the block starting at the (3,0) entry and ending at the (`n`,0) entry, but in fact it refers to the block starting at the (3,0) entry and of size (`n`,0). The block starting at the (3,0) entry and ending at the (`n`,0) entry is denoted by `u_n.block(3,0,n-2,1)` or `u_n.segment(3,n-2)` or `u_n.tail(n-2)`; see the link mentioned at the start.